# How would I overload the except method to compare the first field of a Linq row collection?

Tags: c#, linq, except

How would I overload the except() method to compare only the first field in a row collection? What if I had an unequal number of columns in the two queries below (extra fields in one qry but not the other)?

I've read through some custom equality comparer questions similar to mine but could not find the exact answer for my solution.

Please help me in writing the overload code as I am new to the except method.

```
    //Pass in your two datatables

    //build the queries based on id and name.

    var qry1 = datatable1.AsEnumerable().Select(a => new { ID = a["ID"].ToString(), Name = a["NAME"].ToString() });
    var qry2 = datatable2.AsEnumerable().Select(b => new { ID = b["ID"].ToString(), Name = b["NAME"].ToString()  });


    //detect row deletes - a row is in datatable1 except missing from datatable2
    var exceptAB = qry1.Except(qry2);

    //detect row inserts - a row is in datatable2 except missing from datatable1
    var exceptAB2 = qry2.Except(qry1);


    //then I execute my code here

    if (exceptAB.Any())
    {
        foreach (var id in exceptAB)
        {
      //print to console id and name
        }


    }
    if (exceptAB2.Any())
    {
        foreach (var id in exceptAB2)
        {
     //print to console id and name
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
I solved this by using a linq query. I was storing the ID's in a variable already so I just used Contains() to pull the extra fields I needed.

```
        var vProjectSummary =  from a in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                            where sDelProjSummCheck.Contains(a.Field<string>("ID"))
                            select new
                            {
                                INV_ID = a.Field<string>("ID"),
                                It_Group = a.Field<string>("IT_GROUP"),
                                L6 = a.Field<string>("L6"),
                                Test_Mgr = a.Field<string>("TEST_MGR"),
                                INV_NAME = a.Field<string>("INV_NAME")
                            };



       //
       //
       //
        var vInsProjectSummary = from a in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                                 where sInsProjSummCheck.Contains(a.Field<string>("ID"))
                              select new
                              {
                                  INV_ID = a.Field<string>("ID"),
                                  INV_NAME = a.Field<string>("INV_NAME")
                              };
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you must use Except you don't need to overload the method call you just need to build up a class the extends the IEqualityComparer interface. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx for example usages. The downside is you can't do it with anonymous types, you would have to create a class to store the column data in.

If you don't have to use Except you can accomplish the same results with anonymous types by doing the following:

var exceptAB = qry1.Where(q1 => !qry2.Any(q2 => q2.ID == q1.ID));
   var exceptBA = qry2.Where(q2 => !qry1.Any(q1 => q1.ID == q2.ID));

Comment: Thanks for the response Craig, I ended up using Linq. I was storing the ID's in a string variabl anyways so all I did was query my data tables using those ID's to get the additional fields I needed. I needed 4 extra fields from 1 data table and 1 extra field from the other data table. I edited the code I ended up using above